# Sql Server 2008 - Split Parameter by Space, Return Records LIKE All Split Results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, split

I am passing in a `@Description` parameter to a stored procedure (VARCHAR).  The parameter could be something like `the book`.  I want to return records where the column contains both `the` and `book`.

These records would return:

- `the green book`
- `the huge orange book`

I have a split function to split the `@Description` parameter by the space, but I have no idea how to include this in the where clause ... I also need to ignore the `@Description` parameter when it is `NULL`.

> Disclaimer: I apologize if this was previously asked ... I searched
>   for a while and didn't find anything.

Comment: Do you need to account for punctuation, and or partial matches?  `'%the%book%'` will match your examples, but also `'theology book'` for example.  Other possible solutions may not match `'the, book'` *(weak example, but best I could think of)*.  Could you elaborate on exactly what needs to be found, and what should not be found?

Comment: I need to find records that match every word in `@Description` ... so `the book` and `book the` and `aatheaa aabookaa`.  Those would all return.

Comment: `%the%book%` gets me closer ... but I also need to match `book the` which is not returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to have a result that have all the words on your parameter, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT A.YourFields
FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER() Total FROM dbo.Split(@Description)) B
ON A.YourField LIKE '%' + B.Data + '%'
GROUP BY A.YourFields
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(B.Total)
```

Comment: Because you're using `LIKE '%' + B.Data + '%'` and not accounting for partial matches, punctuation, etc, this is actually very similar to `LIKE '%the%book%'`; same result, a lot more code and a lot more cpu time.

Comment: I tried this ... the problem is when `@Description` is null.  And one of my queries also has the group by for another reason, so the having doesn't work.

Comment: @Martin - Based on your comment to your question, this is probably your answer.  But put it in a sub-query.  `SELECT * FROM yourQuery INNER JOIN (LamaksQuery) AS books ON books.id = yourTable.id WHERE blah`